# Filtering in MS graph by subproperty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to filter lists by their template since I only want to get document libraries, however, when I try to do that as in the following example, I get error `The provided filter statement is not supported`.

```
v1.0/sites/root/lists?$filter=list/template eq 'documentLibrary'
```

Besides that I also tried filtering by `startswith(list/template, 'document')` but with this approach I get `An unspecified error has occurred`.

In general, I'm trying to get document libraries for a root, but querying `/drives` seems to be quite slow (takes around 3 seconds to get them) and I believe that getting them via list could be faster.

Thanks

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself and it appears that filtering on 'list/template' is still unsupported the for the '/lists' API (v1.0 and beta). Also note that the $filter query parameter does not seem to be supported for the '/drives' API. It fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use the Graph API v1.0 endpoints. They have less queryable properties, but are more functional. I would query the 'lists' endpoint and filter by property.

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists

GET /sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/operations
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-list-operations?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http